# Do SWIFT payments with wrong first name still go through?

Tags: international-transfer, online-banking

I'm supposed to receive a payment from another country, yet when I provided the details, I confused the card with my husband's meaning the card holder firstname is wrong.

Do such payments still get processed if the lastname, address, IBAN and SWIFT are correct?

Is there a chance will get rejected? (I'm afraid since payments are made through another company which takes 10 days to process the payment and forward it to the appropriate person).

Comment: I would _hope_ that they reject it if any of the data is wrong, but...

Comment: Would there be a chance the bank would rather contact the person with the specified IBAN (in this case, myself) to clarify the payment without having to send the money back to it's origin and forcing me to go through another 10 days of waiting?

Comment: You're asking about bank policies. Ask the bank....

Answer (score 2):

> Do such payments still get processed if the lastname, address, IBAN and SWIFT are correct? Is there a chance will get rejected?

This depends on the Beneficiary Bank. Some beneficiary banks validate the name and the account number [as both of these are available in their books]. If there is a mismatch, they reject the payment. Quite a few Banks only validate the IBAN, if this is correct, they would just credit this.

Comment: The paymeny went through. Only IBAN was validated I guess.

Comment: @CristianD Good. Like I said it depends on the Bank. Some validate the name some don't.

Comment: Validating the full name would also pose problems for any recipient who has a name that is hard to spell for the sender, or for a recipient who doesn't give their full legal name (which is what most banks will have on their books) to the person sending the money.